# Script with STUFF(...XML PATH function is only partially working, can someone help fix it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL SERVER 2014
The table I am dealing with looks like this *this isn't the exact table*

```
EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher | Paid  | PayTier
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Franco    1000    Tier 1 
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Jeff      1000    Tier 2
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Azeem     1000    Tier 3
  2        10/18/1995  MND       Bye         Rafa      15      Tier 2
  2        10/18/1995  MND       Bye         Ben       15      Tier 2
  3        10/19/1995  LMD .     Go .        Zoe       32      Tier 4
  4        10/20/1995  SND .     Zed .       Claudia   68     Tier 1
```

My Goal was to make rows with the same EventId a single row BUT ALSO have the teachers listed in the row like: Franco,Jeff,Azeem (e.g. for EventId 1)

The result should be like this for example:

```
EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher     | Paid | Tier of Pay
   1     10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello   Franco,Jeff,Azeem  1000  Tier 3
```

This is the script I currently have.. The STUFF(..XML) function is what I am using to achieve the above. (the First + Last name) column in the script is essentially the Teacher column I showed in the example above.

```
SELECT
    a.eventId                                                                            AS [Event_ID]
  , FORMAT(b.eventStartDate, 'd')                                                        AS [Start Date]
  , dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR))                                  AS Categories
  , b.EventName                                                                          AS [Event Name]
  , STUFF(
                                           (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + cast(d1.FirstName + ' ' + d1.LastName as varchar(100)) 
                                            FROM dbo.RetreatSuiteRegistrations a1
                                                 JOIN (SELECT
                                                       t12.attributeId
                                                       , t12.EventId
                                                      , i2.EVENT_TEACHERS
                                                FROM @attribute_table                                    t12
                                                OUTER APPLY dbo.teacherstring3(t12.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i2 ) AS MyTest1 ON a1.EventId = MyTest1.EventId
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteTeacher                                       d1 ON MyTest1.EVENT_TEACHERS = d1.TeacherID 
                                                 where a.EventId = a1.EventId  
                                                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Teachers]

  , FORMAT(SUM(a.totalPaid), 'C')                                                        AS Paid

  , d.Pay_Tier                                                                           AS [Tier of Pay]
  , CASE WHEN 
         d.Pay_Tier = 'Tier 1' THEN '85' 
                        WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 2' THEN '96' 
                        WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 3' THEN '107'
                          WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 4' THEN '117'
                        ELSE SUM(a.totalpaid)*0.4
                    END AS Pay_rate
FROM dbo.RetreatSuiteRegistrations                                   a
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEvents                                        b ON a.EventId = b.EventId
                                                                         AND a.registrationStatusId = 1
                                                                         AND b.spacesAvailable > 0
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEventAttributes                               c ON a.EventId = c.EventId
                                                                         AND c.attributeName = 'EVENT_CATEGORIES'
  JOIN (SELECT
          t1.attributeId
          , t1.EventId
          , i.EVENT_TEACHERS
        FROM @attribute_table                                    t1
          OUTER APPLY dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i ) AS MyTest ON a.EventId = MyTest.EventId
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteTeacher                                       d ON MyTest.EVENT_TEACHERS = d.TeacherID
GROUP BY
    a.eventId
  , b.eventStartDate
  , dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR))
  , b.EventName
  , d.Pay_Tier
  , Pay_rate
ORDER BY b.eventStartDate DESC;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CategoryString;
GO
```

The reason why there are joins in the STUFF(Select function is because the Teacher names are in table variable which I can access only by joining those other tables as well.

The script executes but there are EventIDs which are still in separate rows. for example my table looks like this now (e.g.worked for EventId 1 but not for EventId 2)

```
EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher | Paid  | PayTier
 1       10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello   Franco,Jeff,Azeem 1000    Tier 1 
 2        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Rafa,Ben      1000    Tier 2
 2        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Rafa,Ben     1000    Tier 3
```

How do I fix my script to fix this problem? I appreciate it, I know this is a long body.

Comment: Without looking into it in any depth, maybe you want a `SELECT DISTINCT` in your `STUFF`?

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: @ZLK that worked to solve the repeating teacher names, there are now still EventIds that are in separate rows though so could you see why that would be happening"

Comment: I edited my question to illustrate the problem

Comment: @Azh588 What do you want to have PayTier information for the Eventid 2. How Tier1 is appropriate as it has 1,2 & 3.

Comment: @Roshan say there are 2 teachers for an EventId 2, who are Tier 1 and Tier 2 respectively then I'd like to choose the Max(Pay_tier) which is Tier_2

Comment: Well you're currently grouping by the pay_tier so if you don't want to group by that you need to remove it from the columns you're grouping by (select the max one instead, I guess? And also you'd need to edit the "pay rate" logic to use the max one as well).